# Flutter macOS Desktop project release artifact location

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-desktop

I want to build a macOS app from the Flutter project. I can build it and run fine from Android Studio and command line using the following command:

```
flutter build macos
flutter run -d macos
```

The [documentation says](https://flutter.dev/desktop#macos) the '.app' file is self-contained and can be distributed as it. However, it doesn't say where it's generated. Do you know how to locate the '.app' artifact for macOS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

mine was in build/macos/Build/Products/Release/$APPNAME.app

And yes, it seems to be entirely self-contained and distributable.

Comment: Thanks! That's helpful.